# Using Auth0 for Asp.Net MVC project how to redirect users directly to Signup page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin, auth0

I am implementing Auth0 for Asp.Net mvc project. I want the users to go to signup page directly upon clicking on the signup link.
I see the documentation says

> You can make users land directly on the Signup page instead of the
> Login page by specifying the **screen_hint=signup** parameter when
> redirecting to **/authorize**.

This is what I have in the code, how do I make sure to pass that as parameters:

```
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = returnUrl ?? Url.Action("Login", "Account"),
        },
            "Auth0");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This resolved the issue:

```
var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties();
**authProperties.Dictionary.Add("screen_hint", "signup");**
authProperties.RedirectUri = Url.Action("Login", "Account");
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(authProperties, "Auth0");
```

Now in the startup, we need to fetch the parameter supplied:

```
RedirectToIdentityProvider = notification =>
{
   if (notification.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication)
    {
                // The context's ProtocolMessage can be used to pass along additional query parameters
                // to Auth0's /authorize endpoint.
                var paramsDictionary = notification.OwinContext.Request.Context.Authentication
                    .AuthenticationResponseChallenge?.Properties.Dictionary;

                **if (paramsDictionary != null && paramsDictionary.ContainsKey("screen_hint"))
                {
                    notification.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("screen_hint",
                        paramsDictionary["screen_hint"]);
                }**
   }
```